# How to filter WHERE statement in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a question. How can I put "rank" in the where statement. The dense rank will give 1,2,3,4,5 on some column in the select statement.

But then I want to do `"WHERE rank = 1"` how can I do this?

```
SELECT 
  column_1
, column_2
, column_3
, dense_rank() over (partition by column_1 order by column_2 desc, column_3 desc) as rank,
FROM Table
WHERE rank = 1
Order by rank
```

The error I get is "Unrecognized name: rank at [19:91]"

Please if you don't understand my question or don't like the way its structured, please give me a chance to improve it instead of flagging it and penalizing me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to produce the "named column" you want. For example:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT 
    column_1 , column_2 , column_3, 
    dense_rank() over (partition by column_1 
                       order by column_2 desc, column_3 desc) as rank
  FROM Table
) x
WHERE rank = 1
Order by rank
```

Answer (score 1):

Rank or any other analytical functions would not be recognized in the same query on which it is generated. That’s why it has to be wrapped in an inner query and any filter or usage on it can be done in the outer query.

```
select *
from (
  select
    column_1 , column_2 , column_3, 
    dense_rank() over (partition by column_1 
                   order by column_2 desc, column_3 desc) as rank,
  from my_Table
) Tb
WHERE Tb.rank = 1;
```

Note that order by on rank is meaningless in this case since all the records will have rank as 1 after the filter is applied.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery allows you to do this using `GROUP BY` -- assuming you have no duplicates:

```
SELECT (ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY column_2 desc, column_3 desc LIMIT 1))[ORDINAL(1)].*
FROM `table` t
GROUP BY column_1;
```

No subquery is necessary to return the first row of a group of rows with the same key.